# iterate over Dataframe row by index value and find max

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I need to iterate over df rows based on its index. I need to find the max in the column p1 and fill it in the output dataframe (along with the max p1), the same for the column p2. In each range of my row indexes (sub_1_ica_1---> sub_1_ica_n), there must be only one 1 and one 2 and I need to fill the remaining with zeros. That's why I need to do the operation range by range.

[image]

I tried to split the index name and make a counter for each subject to be used to iterate over the rows, but I feel that I am in the wrong way!

```
    from collections import Counter
    a = df.id.tolist()
    indlist = []
    for x in a:
    i = x.split('_')
    b = int(i[1])
    indlist.insert(-1,b)
    c=Counter(indlist)
    keyInd = c.keys()
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: according to Jerazel example my desired output would look like this.
First I find the max for p1 and p2 columns which will be translated in the new df into 1 and 2, and the remaining fields will be zeros

[image]

Comment: What is `p01`, `p0n` in output?

Comment: for column p0 I don't compute the max I just get it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) with [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html), also if need columns names use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
idx = ['sub_1_ICA_0','sub_1_ICA_1','sub_1_ICA_2','sub_2_ICA_0','sub_2_ICA_1','sub_2_ICA_2']
df = pd.DataFrame({'p0':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'p1':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'p2':[5,9,6,1,2,4]}, index=idx)

print (df)

cols = ['p0','p1','p2']
df['a'] = df[cols].values.argmax(axis=1)
df['b'] = df[cols].max(axis=1)
df['c'] = df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
             p0  p1  p2  a  b   c
sub_1_ICA_0   7   1   5  0  7  p0
sub_1_ICA_1   8   3   9  2  9  p2
sub_1_ICA_2   9   5   6  0  9  p0
sub_2_ICA_0   4   7   1  1  7  p1
sub_2_ICA_1   2   1   2  0  2  p0
sub_2_ICA_2   3   0   4  2  4  p2
```

Comment: here the max is computed for the whole column?

Comment: you did most of the work, but my desired output is a little bit different. 2 columns where the first one indicate 0, 1, 2 according to the position of the max, and the second column with the max value

Comment: Thanks Jerazel, I used your solution to reshape df according to my desired output